# How to set Button clicked programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, linkbutton

I'm using LinkButton(Consider it as Button) in ASP .Net. I need to click that button programmatically using C# code behind. How can I achieve this..?

Comment: c# is server side, are you sure you don't want to use javascript that is client side?

Comment: Is there any problems to add event handler for click event?

Comment: The event handler invokes some logic. No other way that you can invoke that logic?

Comment: Add a method that is called from your click-event-handler and from your other location as well.

Comment: I kept buttons in each rows of GridView. OnClick event has written for buttons in each row. My requirement is to select first row button by default on page load event.

Comment: @Charan: Then encapsulate the logic in the click-handler in a method with an parameter that takes for example an ID and call it from the handler as well as from page_load(you only need to get the ID of the first record there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use event-handlers as methods, their only purpose is to handle events. All functionality should be encapsulated in methods that can be called from within the event-handler as well as from wherever you need it.

```
protected void Button_Click(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs) 
{
     int id=int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     doSomething(id);
}
```

Then you can call this method for example from page's load event as well:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the ID of the first record in GridView's DataSource here or where you databind the GridView
   doSomething(id);
}

public void doSomething(int id) { //do something }
```

How to pass the ID from the GridView record as `CommandArgument`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IdColumn")%>' OnCommand="Button_Click" Text="Do Something">
          </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. but 1 method is to simply call the event handler method code.

But if you're interested in sending the response back to the client and taking the button click as a new request, you can try this out

ASPX:

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton1</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton2_Click">LinkButton2</asp:LinkButton>
```

C#:

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("I was programatically called!");
    }

    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pbref = Page.GetPostBackEventReference(LinkButton1);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "KeyName", "<script>" + pbref + "</script>");
    }
```

However there's 1 problem. You might run in to an event validation error. in which case you might have to disable event validation as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" ... %>
```

I wouldn't recommend it. there are other ways to overcome it..but that's a different google search :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //when the pages is rendered and loaded for the first time execution goes here
        //so... call the method that selects the first row
        SelectsFirtsRow();
    }
    else
    {
     //do something else
     ...
    }
}
protected void FirstRowLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move all the code that selects the first row to a method.
    //you can also supply some arguments if they are needed for method execution... that's up to you
    SelectsFirtsRow();
}
public void SelectsFirtsRow();
{
    //your logic goes here. i.e. selects the first row
}
```

p.s.
invoking event handlers from code behind is a bad practice. event handlers are meant to fire on some client side actions.